# Ubuntu: using docker with snap and firewall is a problem

Tags: docker, ubuntu, firewall, snap

On a ubuntu 21.10, using docker as a snap (snap install docker). With my firewall enabled, i have a problem resolving DNS:

```
$ docker run bash ping www.google.com
```

==> error

```
$ docker run bash ping 8.8.8.8
```

==> ok

If I disable the firewall, all is ok (sudo ufw disable):

```
$ docker run bash ping www.google.com
```

==> ok

My ufw status is like:

> Status: active
>
> To                         Action      From
> --                         ------      ---- 22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                   OpenSSH
> ALLOW       Anywhere                   Samba
> ALLOW       192.168.100.0/24           22/tcp (v6)
> ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              OpenSSH (v6)
> ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

I suspect that the docker container has no access to the internet over TCP (and probably UDP).

What would be the correct config to use to allow docker/snap to pass through the firewall?

Comment: I had issues with the snap version of docker not auto-detecting the DNS configuration properly. If you do a `docker run --dns <your dns server here> bash ping www.google.com` does it work correctly? In the end I removed that version and installed the .deb version directly from Docker.

Comment: I had trouble with the snap version of docker also - couldn't connect to a TCP port from my container. So did 'snap remove docker', installed from Docker.com, still had probs, so rebooted the machine and now it works.